# Animated infinite scrolling via AJAX: returning JSON or HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, json, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to create an infinite scrolling page - somewhat similar to tumblr archive pages like [this](http://rickerlrthemes.tumblr.com/archive). I understand the concept that I have to load the content with a server call, but I don't know how to achieve this "animated loading" design like in Tumblr.

I don't want to know the exact code, only the overall concept of the solution. So what would be the best practice to do things like this?

What should I get from the server: a bunch of **JSON data** or a **full HTML page**?

I have tried to decode the Tumblr page above, and I saw on my network traffic page that in every scroll event there is a POST request which returns a *full* HTML page which has its own JavaScript and CSS content!

I guess that the animation logic is inside of this JavaScript content.

But I have 2 questions about this method:

- When I get the full HTML page from the server (which contains the new page as well), how can I throw the currently displayed HTML document away and I set the new one?
- Isn't it too bad from a performance point of view to return a full HTML document every time? Because the full document would contain the results of the previous "pages" of the archive as well. Or do I think wrong?

Wouldn't it be better to return a JSON-only result from the server? (It have to be parsed on the client but it would be more network traffic-friendly, I guess)

If it would be better to return a JSON, why the Tumblr works on the other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It surely is beneficial to not send lots of data that will not be used.
However, if your server has a lot of resources, you can do some preprocessing on the server instead of client. This means, instead of JSON, you can send an HTML snippet, the block that will be added. Moreover, if your HTML structure is very complex, you don't want to implement it twice; once in HTML and once in Javascript.

The way Tumblr works might be because they don't want to add much more to the server code base, and instead offload the work to the client. **Since only one page is sent at a time, the overhead is constant** w.r.t. the number of pages. The client can just take the full HTML, find the corresponding element with DOM manipulation and place it somewhere.

In fact, that is what the AutoPager plugin does: It learns the "next" link and the page body from the user, then fetches additional *full* pages from the unsuspecting server and inserts their content into the page (and reads the next page url).

In short:

- The benefit of JSON is low bandwidth usage.
- The benefit of HTML snippets is low demands on client processing power, and little to no code duplication.
- The benefit of full HTML is that the server needs not care if it's serving the first page or any other.

Comment: Why is the overhead constant? If I have scrolled down 1000 pages (for example), then the next time I will get a full HTML page which will contain 1001 pages! Instead of a simple 1 page (JSON) response. I think the overhead is linear...

Comment: @Zsolt No. A full HTML page will only contain one page (the 1001st). The server does not send the previous 1000 pages again. The javascript does not _replace_ the current page with what it received. It will _append_ a specific part of it.

Comment: "full" means "including the header and the footer", or "everything the user would see if the website used conventional paging".

Comment: Oh, I see, you're right...Then, I think this constant overhead could be unimportant. And what about animated loading? If I want to achieve this "feature", could it affect the decision on to prefer HTML over JSON?
Because of the "appended" HTML could contain Javascript blocks I think the answer is no...

Comment: The animated loading will certainly push your decision towards JSON and away from a single snippet (if you want to pack multiple posts in one result set), but full HTML is always possible, and may still be easier to implement (server-wise). The single-snippet way no longer provides any benefit concerning computing power, but the benefits of full HTML remain.

Comment: The javascript blocks can be harmless even if appended to the document in if they set themselves to execute at page load, as it is already too late. However, the full page is stripped by the javascript anyways, so the scripts should never get appended to the document. Inline scripts still contribute to the overhead in terms of pure bandwidth.

Comment: What do you mean on benefits on computing power? If I send a HTML snippet to the browser, the server have to generate the code...If I send a JSON the client side have to "foreaching" on the JSON response and run the DOM insertion logic.
Could this be an argument on the one over the another?